# how do I change line foreground color on regex in vim?

Tags: vim

How do I change the foreground text color of a line in vim if it contains some words ?  For example, I want all my assert() macros to display in gray color, so they are less visible to my eyes. My code could be something like this:

```
void add_cmd_to_history(void) {
    uint32_t index;

    ASSERT_D1(history_num_lines<MAX_HISTORY_SIZE);
    index=history_num_lines*MAX_CMD_LINE_BUF_ALLOC_LEN;
    strcpy(&history[index],cmd_line_buf);
    history_num_lines++;
}
```

So , in my .vimrc I will need to regex for the string 'ASSERT_D1' and if it is matching, change the 'ctermfg' to 'gray' or some other color. I already have C language syntax hiliting, therefore I need this rule to be applied at the end of all my plugins. How is this done in vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highlighting on top of existing syntax highlighting is best done via the `:match` commands:

```
:highlight Assertions ctermfg=gray guifg=gray
:2match Assertions /\<ASSERT_D1\>[^;]*;/
```

This is scoped to the current window. If you mainly edit C/C++ files, you can define this globally in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd VimEnter,WinEnter * 2match Assertions /\<ASSERT_D1\>[^;]*;/
```

Or, put the command in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim`, but then it will not apply automatically to split windows / tabs (no problem if you don't use splits).

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I already got into the syntax files under /usr/share but its good such complicated stuff can be avoided.

Comment: Would be nice to make it work on splits too. How do I apply it automatically on split activation?

Comment: I found it : BufWinEnter !